# Node.js fix dirty JSON requests

Tags: node.js, json, body-parser

I am receiving JSON to my node.js API, The json is typically good. However it sometimes
has bad characters at the end.

```
{
  "test": "test"
}���
```

I am looking to intercept that before it gets to the BodyParser that blows up.
Is this possible? I tried putting a middleware function in front of the bodyparser but it doesn't help.
Here is what I currently have:

```
    import { RegisterRoutes } from './routes/routes';
import * as swaggerUi from 'swagger-ui-express';

const app = express();
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: ['http://localhost:4200'],
    credentials: true,
  })
);

app.use(bodyparser.json());
app.use(requestLoggerMiddleware);
RegisterRoutes(app);
```

Sadly, the source json can not be controlled at this time. I know how to fix it, if I can capture it. But I am not sure how to get the data before it gets to the body parser.

Comment: if you're sure that this is a problem with the JSON being sent by the client, can you not just respond with an HTTP 400?

Comment: The data is being sent from a radio transmitter that sits in a field (I am actively trying to get it to transmit clean noise free data). The data is always complete and correct minus the bad data at the end. I have yet to determine if the data is being caused by interference from other transmitters, OR if it is due to a noisy power source.
But If I could clean the good data, that would be optimal.

Answer (score 0):

if you can guarantee that your JSON contains only printable ASCII characters then you can remove your noise with a regexp in your middleware:

```js
const sanitizedInput = rawInput.replace(/[^\x20-\x7E]+/, '');
```

if that doesn't work for you, and if the noise is guaranteed to follow a well-formed payload, then you can find the last `}` in that payload and remove everything after it:

```js
const sanitizedInput = rawInput.slice(0, 1 + rawInput.lastIndexOf(`}`));
```

your middleware will have to be added before your call to `app.use(bodyparser.json());` for either of these methods to work.

Comment: I don't think this advice will entirely work, as bodyparser will attempt to read the body from the stream. If something read the stream and sanitized the body before, bodyparser will fail.

Comment: It might be better to for OP to write their own `bodyparser.json()` equivalent instead.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is with this line:

```
app.use(bodyparser.json())
```

It is defined before your register your router. So it will always capture the JSON request first. You can remove the **app.use** and directly place **bodyparser.json** in your routes.

Comment: body-parser does not "capture the json request".  [it populates `req.body`](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html).  if an API only speaks JSON then it's 100% appropriate to use it as middleware which gets executed before any route-specific handlers.  The problem is that the middleware is being passed something other than JSON (i.e. the noise) which must be removed before that middleware gets executed.